# MongoDB Database Tool installation issue Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, git-bash

I am trying to install the MongoDB Database Tools. I am using Windows and Git Bash terminal. I downloaded the collection from MongoDB. The installation instructions say "Once downloaded, unpack the archive and copy the tools to a location on your hard drive" which doesn't seem very descriptive to me. I have the tools folder in my Program Files/MongoDB. When I try to run 'mongoimport --version' in Git Bash I get the response 'bash: mongoimport: command not found'. Any help getting the tools running would be much appreciated.

Comment: I got it to work by navigating into the tools folder and then running './mongoimport.exe' followed by the appropriate flags and such.  Anyone know why I can't run this from the command line with just 'mongoimport' as the docs seem to suggest?

Comment: What version of MongoDB?

Comment: @prasad_ version 4.4.0

Comment: You can add the directory where you placed the tools to PATH, or place the tools into a directory which is already in PATH.

Comment: @D.SM Thank you! This helped me figure this out. Do the designated paths always have to point to a 'bin' folder?

Comment: This is a unix convention but not a windows one. In windows do what you like, either way works.